# vbScript code to cghheck workday date of T-1

Tags: excel, date, vbscript

I want to write a vbScript where I take the previous working days date (today - 1, workday) then I check a range of cells in an excel doc `A6:B19` to check they are equal.

Issue being - does vbScript have `TODAY()` and `WORKDAY()` function like excel have?

Comment: VBScrpt has a `Date` function that is equivalent to Excel's `TODAY()`, but it doesn't have a `Workday` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the `Date()` & `Time()` functions to get the current date & time. As far as I know there is no separate workday function, but you can always use `Application.WorksheetFunction` to access all the functions that are available in excel. So in your case you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Workday`.